# PHP XMLWriter, how to insert a line break?

Tags: php, xml, xmlwriter

I'm using XMLWriter http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php to let my webclient create an XML File. 
In the beginning there has to be an element with very many attributes, like this:

```
$xml->startElement('registry-request');
$xml->writeAttribute('att1', 'long text');
$xml->writeAttribute('att2', 'long text');
$xml->writeAttribute('att3', 'long text');
$xml->writeAttribute('att4', 'long text');
```

So that part in the XML file will look something like this:

```
<registry-request att1="long text" att2="long text" att3="long text" att4="long text">
```

Which with real input looks quite terrible.

I would much rather have it like this:

```
<registry-request att1="long text" att2="long text" 
att3="long text" att4="long text">
```

I didn't find a solution in the XMLWriter php.net documentation, anyone got an idea how to do this? Just adding typical linebreak commands like:

```
$xml->writeAttribute('att2', 'long text\n');
```

doesn't help.

Thanks.

Comment: Try it with `"long text\n"` as single quotes don't interprete `\n` as new line but as literal output

Comment: `XMLWriter` is designed to produce machine-readable code. As such, it does not give this kind of control over the output. If you want something that will pretty-print the output in exactly the way you want it to appear, you may have to roll your own. Or use a viewer that allows you to format it's display.

Comment: unfortunately there's nothing you can do to make that happen with XMLWriter, manipulating your parameters by doing "long text\n" will give you a new line BEFORE your closing doublequote and you'll have it on the new line with the new attribute, which won't be so pretty.
as for "prettifying" your output, I believe XMLWriter has only setIndent() and setIndentString()

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually the `$xml->setIndent(1);` does exactly that. Surprisingly!