# PHP XMLWriter output format for testing

Tags: php, xmlwriter

I have been asked by the recipient of my XML messages to add newline characters at the end of each element.  They have asked for this as the message goes directly into an Oracle database and they can only view it as one long string which makes testing difficult.  Their current workaround it to open it in Internet Explorer but this takes time

It there a way to add a newline character at the end of each element?

I have tried adding the following at the end of each element

```
print (chr(13).chr(10));
```

But this has no effect on the output.  Here is the start of my message

```
$writer = new XMLWriter();  
$writer->openURI('php://output');
$writer->startDocument('1.0','UTF-8');   
$writer->setIndent(TRUE);   
    $writer->startElement('vehicleServiceRequest'); 
        $writer->startElement('vehicleDetails');
            $writer->writeElement('companyIdentifier', $AIS_transmission_code);
            $writer->writeElement('transportCompanyName', $user['company_name']);
            $writer->writeElement('dispatchNumber', $booking_reference);                            
            $writer->writeElement('plannedDispatchDate', date("Y-m-dTH:i:s"));                      // We use today as the planned dispatch date
            $writer->writeElement('dispatchPostCode', $user['postcode']);                           
            $writer->writeElement('dispatchCountryCode', 'UK');
```

and here is the output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><vehicleServiceRequest><vehicleDetails><companyIdentifier>001</companyIdentifier><transportCompanyName>Mixed Freight Services</transportCompanyName><dispatchNumber>174672</dispatchNumber>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP XMLWriter, how to insert a line break?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10207455/php-xmlwriter-how-to-insert-a-line-break)

Comment: I did view that answer but I am looking for a CRLF in the message to make it more readable not a newline in that data.  That said I have just tried
$writer->setIndentString(PHP_EOL); which is doing part of the job.  I now hve three line feeds at the end of each element but lost the overall formatting when viewing in Notepad++

Answer (score 5):

I know it's an old thread but since I see no helpful reply, below is the line of code you're missing to have the XML file correctly indented.

```
$writer->setIndent(TRUE); // after your line of code add the below line
$writer->setIndentString('    '); // here you just have to add the string you wish to use for indentation; in this case I used 4 spaces
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll add that now.